# How can I notify the cometd server instance when I get JMS message on Message driven bean?

Tags: java, servlets, ejb, atmosphere, cometd

I have read somewhere that the Cometd is container specific and we cannot inject into an EJB container. I have an application in which there are MDBs defined and the messages received are somehow should be sent to the web clients. Is it possible?

I appreciate any inputs. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CometD](http://cometd.org) is **not** container specific, it will work in any Servlet 3 container using Asynchronous Servlets.

CometD relies on [Jetty](http://eclipse.org/jetty) classes for its implementation, and scales best when deployed in Jetty, but there are users that deploy CometD in Tomcat, GlassFish, etc.

Having said that, if you deploy CometD into a JEE server and have MDBs, you can easily convert the MDB message into a CometD message and have CometD send it to clients.

The actual details of how to wire the MDB to CometD depend on the frameworks you use (e.g. Spring, CDI, custom, etc.), but typically the MDB needs to lookup/notify a CometD service, and have the CometD service broadcast the CometD message.

You can find the [CometD server-side tutorial](http://docs.cometd.org/tutorials/) very similar (although it's not using MDBs) to what you need. In that tutorial, the role of the MDB is played by the `StockPriceEmitter` class.

Look also at the [CometD reference manual](http://docs.cometd.org/reference) for further information.

Comment: I have to improve my question. When I say container specific, my point is we cannot inject the Bayeux Server instance in EJB cotainer. The cometd runs only on servlet engine that supports asynchronous channels. Yes the stock price emitter is similar to the the MDB. In case of MDB that runs on EJB container how do I lookup or Notify. In my Java EE knowledge I think the only way to notify is it has to make a servlet call every time when it receives a JMS message. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: CometD 2.x runs in *any* Servlet Container, even only Servlet 2.5 compliant. It will be a lot less scalable due to the blocking nature of those containers, apart Jetty 7 which is a Servlet 2.5 compliant container but allows for asynchronous features.

Comment: How to lookup other components from an MDB depends on what you actually use. For example, Spring allows you to inject dependencies in the MDB, and therefore you can inject the CometD service. Alternatively you can use the Singleton or ServiceLocator patterns, or perhaps even CDI events.

Comment: If you want to see a better integration of CometD with JEE components, please file an issue at the [CometD Issue Tracker](http://bugs.cometd.org).

Comment: Wow, If I could inject the CometD service into MDB, that would be great. Could you please point some document or tutorial which injects CometD service on MDB? Thanks very much for the detailed answers and your time. :-)

Comment: You did not tell what you're using, whether Spring, plain JEE, CDI or something else. Google is your friend to find instructions on how to inject stuff into MDBs.  As I said, CometD support can be definitely improved on this area. I'll try to find some time to write a CometD - CDI tutorial.

Comment: Sorry. I use the plain JEE, Websphere 8.5/Jboss 7.1. I tried to deploy  a sample cometd application on these servlet engines and it works. I use Commonj threads on servlet container to listen for JMs messages and then use the CometD service to route back to web clients. In this scenario I will have to manage all the JMS connections. I thought it would be better solution when I use MDBs instead of threads. I am eager to see your CometD tutorial. Thanks.

Comment: you are correct, I think CDI events helps here to observe events fired by MDB in the web tier. I will try this method. Thanks.